# How to use vertical-align: middle

Tags: html, css

live: http://jsfiddle.net/8hAv3/

```
#main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
#sub {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<div id="main">
    <div id="sub">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Why in this example vertical-align not working? How can i make it? I dont want use margin, padding and set height in px. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there CSS Alternatives to the Deprecated HTML Attributes "align" and "valign"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367387/are-there-css-alternatives-to-the-deprecated-html-attributes-align-and-valign)

Comment: The CSS property `vertical-align` only works on inline-block elements – not on block (e.g. a div) or inline elements.

Comment: This is a well known duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
}
#sub {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8hAv3/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to vertically center text in a fixed height box I would use `line-height:100px` to do it

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a

```
display:table-row; 
display:table-cell; or 
display:table;
```

along with the vertical-align style, not sure which exact display value it has to be but it needs to be one of the `table` ones.

Comment: If you're not sure about how to answer the question properly, do your research first and answer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display:table` on the main container and `display:table-cell` on the child. Illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/8hAv3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the element #sub a line height, otherwise the browser doesn't know how high it is to vertically align it.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the div a `line-height`.

```
 #main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
#sub {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UCRfV/)

This solution does not use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` as `display:table` and `display:table-cell` are not browsers friendly, some older browsers do not support